# How do I calculate average number of ride per week from Total Count in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

My dataframe (df) is a 12 months data which consist of 5m rows. One of the columns is `day_of_week` which are Monday to Sunday. This df also has a unique key which is the `ride_id` column. I want to calculate the average number of rides per day_of_week. I have calculated the number of rides per day_of_week using

```py
copydf.groupby(['day_of_week']).agg(number_of_rides=('day_of_week', 'count'))
```

However, I find it hard to calculate the mean/average for each day of week. I have tried:

```py
copydf.groupby(['day_of_week']).agg(number_of_rides=('ride_id', 'count')).mean()
```

and

```
avg_days = copydf.groupby(['day_of_week']).agg(number_of_rides=('ride_id', 'count'))
avg_days.groupby(['day_of_week']).agg('number_of_rides', 'mean')
```

They didn't work. I want the output to be in three columns, day_of_week, number_of_rides, and avg_num_of_ride or two columns day_of_week or weekday_num and avg_num_of_rides

This is my df. kindly note that code block have tampered with some columns line due to the long column names.

```
    ride_id rideable_type   started_at  ended_at    start_station_name  start_station_id    end_station_name    end_station_id  start_lat   start_lng   end_lat end_lng member_or_casual    ride_length year    month   day_of_week hour    weekday_num
0   9DC7B962304CBFD8    electric_bike   2021-09-28 16:07:10 2021-09-28 16:09:54 Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 13022   Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 13022   41.89   -87.68  41.89   -87.67  casual  2   2021    September   Tuesday 16  1
1   F930E2C6872D6B32    electric_bike   2021-09-28 14:24:51 2021-09-28 14:40:05 Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 13022   Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 13022   41.94   -87.64  41.98   -87.67  casual  15  2021    September   Tuesday 14  1
2   6EF72137900BB910    electric_bike   2021-09-28 00:20:16 2021-09-28 00:23:57 Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 13022   Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 13022   41.81   -87.72  41.80   -87.72  casual  3   2021    September   Tuesday 0   1
```

This is the output I desire

```
    number_of_rides average_number_of_rides
day_of_week 
Saturday    964079  50.4
Sunday  841919       70.9
Wednesday   840272   90.2
Thursday    836973    77.2
Friday  818205        34.4
Tuesday 814496       34.4
Monday  767002        200.3
```

Again, I have calculated the number of ride per day_of_week, what I want to do is just to add the third column or better still, have average_ride per weekday(Monday or 0, Tuesday or 1, Wednesday or 2) on its own output df

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to show us a sample of your dataframe ?

Comment: Can you provide your expected sample dataframe? The average/mean has to be computed on some number field. Which number field do you have in your input dataframe for average/mean?

Comment: Hello @AzharKhan Khan. I have added the df sample and reframed the question in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get average number of rides per week day, you need total rides on that week day and number of weeks.

You can compute the week number from date:

```py
df["week_number"] = df["started_at"].dt.isocalendar().week

>>    ride_id started_at day_of_week  week_number
>> 0        1 2021-09-20      Monday           38
>> 1        2 2021-09-21     Tuesday           38
>> 2        3 2021-09-20      Monday           38
>> 3        4 2021-09-21     Tuesday           38
>> 4        5 2021-09-27      Monday           39
>> 5        6 2021-09-28     Tuesday           39
```

Then group by `day_of_week` and `week_number` to compute an aggregate dataframe:

```py
week_number_group_df = df.groupby(["day_of_week", "week_number"]).agg(number_of_rides_on_day=("ride_id", "count"))

>>                             number_of_rides_on_day
>> day_of_week   week_number                          
>> Monday        38                                  2
>>               39                                  1
>> Tuesday       38                                  2
>>               39                                  1
```

Use the aggregated dataframe to get the final results:

```py
week_number_group_df.groupby("day_of_week").agg(number_of_rides=("number_of_rides_on_day", "sum"), average_number_of_rides=("number_of_rides_on_day", "mean"))

>>              number_of_rides  average_number_of_rides
>> day_of_week                                          
>> Monday                     3                   1.5000
>> Tuesday                    3                   1.5000
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you're not trying to compute the average over a field in your grouped data (as @Azhar Khan pointed out), but an averaged count of rides per weekday over your original 12-months period.

Basically, you need two elements:

- First, the count of rides per weekday you observe in your dataframe. That's exactly what you get with `copydf.groupby(['day_of_week']).agg(number_of_rides=('ride_id', 'count'))`
  Let's say you get something like:

[image]

- Secondly, the count of weekdays in your period. Let's imagine you're considering the year 2022 as an example, you can get such data with the next code snippet:

```
df_year = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('01-01-2022'), 
                                          end=pd.to_datetime('31-12-2022'), 
                                          freq='1D'), 
                       columns=['date'])
df_year["day_of_week"] = df_year["date"].dt.weekday
nb_weekdays_in_year = df_year.groupby('day_of_week').agg(nb_days=('date', 'count'))
```

This gives such a dataframe:

[image]

Once you have both these dataframes, you can simply join them with
`nb_weekdays_in_year.join(nb_rides_per_day)` for instance, and you just need to perform the ratio of both colums to get your average.

The difficulty here lies in the fact you need to get the total number of weekdays of each type over your period, that you cannot get from your observation directly I guess (what if there's some missing value ?). Plus, let's underline you're not trying to get an intra-group average, so that you cannot use simple agg functions like 'mean' directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it didn't work. Your first and second steps resulted in same result. Count of day_of_week and count of 'Date' gave same result, so I didn't bother to join.

Comment: You mean number of rides vs number of days of week over your period ? Because in one case you should start with your datagrams, and in the other one, it's just considering the fact a 12-months period does not have an equal number of days of week (if you have a count of number of rides, just dividing by 52 might give you a good approximation)

Answer (score -1):

Using pivot we can solve this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/content/test.csv')
df.head()

# sample df

    date        rides
0   2019-10-01  1
1   2019-10-02  2
2   2019-10-03  5
3   2019-10-04  3
4   2019-10-05  2

df['date] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# extracting the week Number
df['weekNo'] = df['date'].dt.week

    date       rides weekNo
0   2019-10-01  1   40
1   2019-10-02  2   40
2   2019-10-03  5   40
```

#### Method 1: Use Pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(values='rides',index='weekNo',aggfunc='mean')
```

output

```
       rides
weekNo  
40    2.833333
41    2.571429
42    4.000000
```

#### Method 2: Use groupby.mean()

```
df.groupby('weekNo')['rides'].mean()
```

Comment: That does not answer OP's question to me. He's asking about the average number of rides per weekday (not week). Plus, 2.833 does not mean anything in the case of week 40 : you're interpreting it as if the count of rides could be distributed evenly between the days (like an equivalent average number of observation per day).